# How to take user input in Node.js - ESM not CJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am doing a project where I am supposed to create a JavaScript RPG CLI game using Node.js. I am supposed to use ESM and not CommonJS. Once executed, the script has to output *Welcome* with a menu underneath where you choose to either start the game, load or exit the game. Then, it demands user input to choose an option.

I have put `type: 'module'` in my package.json to use ESM. I tried with *readline* and with inquirer.js but nothing works. I installed inquirer.js with `npm i inquirer`, imported it but it doesn't work. I literally just started this project, I basically have but few lines of the code. I don't know where the problem is.

Here is one of the codes that I tried:

```js
import readline from "readline";
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from "node:process";

const run = (args) => {
  console.clear();

  console.log(`
    +-----------------------------+
    |          Welcome !          |
    +-----------------------------+
    `);
  console.log(`
    1. Start game 
    2. Load game 
    3. Exit ❌
    `);

  const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

  rl.question("Your choice (1-3): ");

  rl.close();
};

export default run;
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Just `import readline from "readline"` and use it.

Comment: Can you actually show some code? It's pretty hard to help you otherwise..

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```js
import readline from "readline";
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from "node:process";

const run = (args) => {
  console.clear();

  console.log(`
    +-----------------------------+
    |          Welcome !          |
    +-----------------------------+
    `);
  console.log(`
    1. Start game 
    2. Load game 
    3. Exit ❌
    `);

  const rl = readline.createInterface({ 
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  rl.question("Your choice (1-3): ", (in)=>{
    //your code here
    // example:
    switch () {
      case 1:
        start();
        break();
      case 2:
        load();
        break();
      case 3:
        exit();
        break();
    }
    rl.close()
});
};

export default run;
```

Of course you need to create `start()`, `load()` and `exit()` functions